# get all values triple pointer C++

Tags: c++, pointers, dll

I have an externel C-DLL, which I use in my C++ project.
The function which I stuck up with is
`Get_ALLFiles(char*** listOfFiles, int* nbrOfFiles)`. This function applies some criteria on a folder and returns the files, that matches the criteria.

```
int nbrOfFiles= 0;
//just get the number of files 
Get_ALLFiles((char***)malloc(1 * sizeof(char***)), &ElementNbr);

// pointer allocation 
char ***MyFilesList = (char***)malloc(nbrOfFiles* sizeof(char**));
for (int i = 0; i < ElementNbr; i++) {
    MyFilesList [i] = (char**)malloc(ElementNbr * 32 * sizeof(char*));
    for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++)
        MyFilesList [i][j] = (char*)malloc(ElementNbr * sizeof(char));
}

//Now i will use the function in order to get all the files (in my exemple 
//I have 10 which respond the criteria 
Get_ALLFiles(MyFilesList , &nbrOfFiles);
```

In my "MyFilesList" I have only the first element, how can I get all the elements in "MyFilesList"?

Comment: Don't actively strive to become a [three-star programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer), it's *not* a compliment. Also, `malloc(1 * sizeof(char***))` would give you something of type `char****` which is even worse, and is masked by the cast. Lastly, don't use `malloc` in C++, use `new` or `new[]`.

Comment: How `Get_ALLFiles` is supposed to be called? Who should allocate the memory? Are your "pointer allocation" loops underpinned by `Get_ALLFiles` requirements or just your guess how to call `Get_ALLFiles`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My ***guess*** is that the function allocates its memory itself, and you should pass pointers to variables that receives the values. *Emulating* pass-by-reference in C.

Something like

```
char** MyFilesList;
int NumberFiles;

// Get a list of all files
Get_ALLFiles(&MyFilesList, &NumberFiles);

// Print all files
for (int i = 0; i < NumberFiles; ++i)
{
    std::cout << "File #" i + 1 << " is " << MyFilesList[i] << '\n';
}

// Free the memory
for (int i = 0; i < NumberFiles; ++i)
{
    free(MyFilesList[i]);
}
free(MyFilesList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the address of a variable to the function, not a pointer to dynamic memory.
That is, just like you do with the number.

The function will then allocate all the memory and update your variable through the pointer it received.

Like this:

```
char** MyFilesList = nullptr;
int nbrOfFiles = 0;
Get_ALLFiles(&MyFilesList , &nbrOfFiles);
```